# Как работает метод onActivityResult?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

Если я правильно понимаю, он автоматически получает содержимое интента, который возвращает дочерняя активность с помощью метода startActivityForResult, и позволяет работать с этим содержимым. Правильно ли я понимаю назначение этого метода или есть ещё что-то, о чём я не знаю?

Comment: может код какой-то покажите а то так сложно что-то предполагать)

Comment: немного неясна суть вопроса. Вы хотите узнать, как вообще используется метод (для каких целей)? Или Вам нужен конкретный пример как им пользоваться в определенном случае?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, хочу узнать, как вообще используется метод

Comment: Параметры передаются при необходимости как в дочернюю активность так и из нее

Comment: обычно это используется для того, чтобы вызвать новую активность, а при ее закрытии получить из нее какие то данные в той активности, которая вызывала новую